# Exporting data from multiple mongo collections using one single query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoexport

How to export `mongo` data from `multiple` `collections` ?

I have three collections A , B , C.

```
Mongo_Host 
|
Master_DB 
    |______ A_Records
    |______ B_Records
    |______ C_Records
```

I know how to export data from individual collections.

```
$mongoexport -h Mongo_Host -d Master_DB -c A_Records -q '{"last_seen_on":{"$gt":1500508800,"$lt":1500594900}}'   -o /home/results/A_Records.json
```

Now , How can i run same sort of query on all the collections 
`( A_Records, B_Records, C_Records )` and Output the results to individual JSONs ( `A_Records.json , B_Records.json , C_Records.json` ) using one single `query` ?

I'm new in handling `mongo`. Any suggestions on how to do this please  ?

Comment: MongoDB queries only really work on "one collection at a time", or at least as far as `mongoexport` is concerned. Simply run three different exports, and from different shells or otherwise launch parallel processes from scripting language of choice if it's a time sensitive issue. You want separate output files anyway, so separate processes just makes sense. There are no "input" or "output" **wildcards** if that is what you were expecting. And before you ask questions, just [consult the manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) that tells you the same thing.

Comment: Thanks Neil. I taut may be there might be some options to do this. But couldn't file any. I will write up some scripts to do this anyway.

Comment: Well next time before "you think there might be something" actually read the manual page and if it is not there then it does not do it. It's not really in the best interests to hide features for command line tools. API's are another story though :)